# Positive Lookahead Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^(?=.{8}$).+
```

The way I understand this is it will accept 8 of any type of character, followed by 1 or more of any character. I feel I am not grasping how a *Positive Lookahead* works. Because both sections of the Regex are looking for '.' wouldn't any series of characters fit this?

My question is, how does the positive lookahead effect this regex and what is an example of a matching string?

The following did not match when supplied in the following [regex tool](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx):

- 123456781
- (12345678)1
- (12345678)
- (abcdefgh)a
- (abcdefgh)
- abc
- 123

EDIT: Removed first two data entries as I clearly wasn't using the regex tool correctly as they now match with exactly 8 characters.

Comment: Your regex has the same meaning as `^.{8}$` I don't get why you use look-ahead for this (unless this is part of a bigger regex).

Comment: It was a regex supplied to me for a validator, I too don't understand their choice now that I see how it works! I think that's what threw me off initially.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`^(?=.{8}$).+`

will match the string

`aaaaaaaa`

Reasoning:

The content inside of the brackets is a lookahead, since it starts with `?=`.

The content inside of a lookahead is parsed - it is not interpreted literally.

Thus, the lookahead only allows the regex to match if `.{8}$` would match (at the start of the string, in this case). So the string has to be exactly eight characters then it has to end, as evidenced by `$`.

Then .+ will match those eight characters.

Comment: Why would one use the positive lookahead trick instead of matching directly 8 characters, like this: `^.{8}$`?

Answer (score 6):

It is trying to match:

```
^               # start of line, but...
(?=.{8}$)       # only if it precedes exactly 8 characters and the end of line
.+              # this one matches those 8 characters
```

and from your input, it should also match these ([try this engine](http://regexpal.com/) with match at line breaks checked):

```
12345678
abcdefgh
```

Comment: I must have had trailing whitespace or one of the incorrect options set as I am now getting matches for these. Have updated my question for clarity for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Matching 12345678 works in ruby:

```
'12345678' =~ /^(?=.{8}$).+/ 
=> 0
```

Maybe your test site don't support look ahead on regexps?

Comment: The test site does support lookahead, at least on the .NET flavour it was default set on. I know because that's how I tested his regex :)